# java. Получение информации о IBM WebSphere программно

Tags: java

Как на java программно получить информацию о IBM WebSphere (версия, число профилей)?
Приложение Desktop, т.е. на самой WebSphere не установлено

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать свой легкий микросервис, который по REST API будет отдавать нужную информацию. Если вы знаете Java, микросервис можно написать, например, с помощью [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), или просто на PHP, это не принципиально. Таким образом вы не будете ограничены только версией и числом профилей, а сможете отдавать совершенно любую интересующую информацию о состоянии сервера.

Откуда он будет брать данные для выдачи? Из стандартных скриптов versioninfo и [manageprofiles](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/was_install/r_WAS_IHS_tools.htm) (с аргументом –listProfiles).

Скрипт versioninfo можно найти так:

- Windows : `%WAS_HOME%\bin\versionInfo.bat`
- Unix/Linux : `$WAS_HOME/bin/versionInfo.sh`

Скрипт manageprofiles можно найти так:

- Windows: `%WAS_HOME%\bin\manageprofiles.bat –listProfiles`
- UNIX/Linux: `$WAS_HOME/bin/manageprofiles.sh –listProfiles`

Переменная `$WAS_HOME` - это каталог, куда установлена WebSphere.

Comment: Я знаю, что в WebSphere есть bat файлы, которые при запуске выдают массу интересной информации. А как вытянуть эту информацию из консоли в приложение? Думаю способ есть, но пока не знаю даже с какой стороны подступиться

Comment: и? Такой ответ не подходит? Продолжить мысль

Comment: Можно ли другими способами, например с помощью библиотеки com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar?

Comment: Я не знаю такого, может кто еще что-нибудь подскажет. 
Если у вас на сервере Linux, то из джавы можно запустить SSH-клиент и дергать нужные скрипты оттуда. Если вы не знаете как написать микросервис, который будет отдавать выхлоп скриптов, или как запустить SSH-клиент, я могу подумать над этим. Возможно, нужно будет оформить это в виде отдельного вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, есть спецификация JMX и IBM ее поддерживает.
Во-вторых, можно просто используя Runtime.exec выполнить исполняемый батничек.
И наконец, можно воспользоваться AdminClient (там  есть библиотеки для  получения системной информации)